# Is it possible to have node.js communicate with a .net API?

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, api

I basically have a service which runs an API which can be accessed using c#. I've been playing about with it but want to make the interface web based now. Is it possible to have a node.js server which interfaces with the API and if so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, this sounds like a perfect use for [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into this.